# how to such a mysql join

Tags: mysql

i have such tables:

`movie: id, user, title`

`thank: id, user, movie`

what i need is to get count of thanks made TO specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be by

```
select count(*) from `thank` t join `movie` m on t.user=m.user 
  where m.user='<specific_usr>';
```

or if both have same field then why don't simply use

```
 select count(*) from `thank` where user='<specific_usr>';
```

or if you want count for all user then try:

```
 select user,count(*) from `thank` group by user;
```

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thank WHERE user='specific user';
```